# why information_schema.tables.data_free always be 8388608?

Tags: mysql

Dose any one knows why information_schema.tables.data_free in InnoDB always be 8388608, no matter how many rows in tables;

```
table_schema    table_name  table_rows  data_free   engine

g33v1       appraise    0       8388608     InnoDB

g33v1       areatype    12403       8388608     InnoDB

g33v1       atype       581982      8388608     InnoDB

g33v1       atype2      579700      8388608     InnoDB
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the temporary table maximum size allocated for doing sorting and other things which requires the space on HDD. As the same things appears in other cases also

```
mysql> show global variables like '%tmp%';
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name  | Value                 |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| bdb_tmpdir     | /usr/local/mysql/tmp/ |
| max_tmp_tables | 32                    |
| tmp_table_size | 8388608               |
| tmpdir         | /usr/local/mysql/tmp  |
+----------------+-----------------------+

mysql> show global variables like '%myisam%';
+---------------------------------+---------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value         |
+---------------------------------+---------------+
| myisam_data_pointer_size        | 4             |
| myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size | 2147483648    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size       | 2147483647    |
| myisam_recover_options          | OFF           |
| myisam_repair_threads           | 1             |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size         | 4194304       |
| myisam_stats_method             | nulls_unequal |
+---------------------------------+---------------
```

Comment: Hi, Vineet. thanks for your answer. I checked this problem again, and find out that the reason why data_free is the same to all tables is because I didn't set innodb_file_per_table. So the data_free is meaning the data_free of idbdata. That is to say the value should be equal to all the tables. Is that right?